# Jenkins pipeline script variables being overwritten?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a jenkins pipeline script that runs various test suites in parallel over multiple nodes. I'm not a jenkins expert - most of this is copy and paste from other jobs we have.

I am occasionally getting failures where the archiveArtefacts command has somehow gotten the wrong 'tar_file' variable.

Normally, the suite name is built into the tar file of logs, then the tar file is archived to Jenkins, but for some runs, the tar file gets created with one suite name, then the archive step has a different name (I've seen runs where 2 or 3 of the parallel steps fail with this sort of error, and some where only 1 fails).

So somehow, between `sh("tar -czf ${tar_file} ${host_logs}/*")` and `archiveArtifacts artifacts: tar_file` the value of `tar_file` has changed to that of a different suite.

Any thoughts on how I can change this so that the tar_file stays constant in each step?

```
try {
    stage('cuke_regression') {
        def stepsForCuke = [:]
        stepsForCuke['cuke_api'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("api")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_admin'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("admin")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_notification'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("notification")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_public'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("public")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_project'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("project")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_group'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("group")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_review'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("review")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_workflow'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("workflow")
        stepsForCuke['cuke_review_comment'] = sectionCukeRegressionTests("review_comment")
        parallel stepsForCuke
    }
} 

def sectionCukeRegressionTests(suite) {
    section = 'cukes'
    return {
        section: {
            node('docker-node') {
                tar_file = "cukes-"+suite+"-logs.tgz "
                try {
                        sh("docker-compose exec ... run the tests \"")
                        sh("tar -czf ${tar_file} ${host_logs}/*")
                } finally {
                    sh("docker-compose down")
                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: tar_file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently the value of `tar_file` is being overridden by the parallel runs between your steps. Try with `def tar_file` instead to limit the scope of this variable within the function.

Comment: Many thanks - will give that a try!

Comment: using 'def' seems to have nicely fixed the problem - many thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Dibakar's suggestion of making the tar_file  variable a 'def' variable has fixed the problem for me.